# Angular: Comunicate through controllers and directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controllers

I'm learning Angular, I have a simple directive that render a `select`. On the `ng-change` of that select I'm calling a method in the controller of my directive:

```
$scope.changeSelect = function(selectedValue) {
  exampleService.setNewValue(selectedValue)
}
```

that service that I have created, updates an example value I have created.

Besides that, I have another controller and a view that renders the directive.
In that view.

How can I tell the controller that the directive has changed, and do something with the data?

Comment: Seriously, this gets asked about 10 times a day.... do a google search, there are so many examples. I've wrote about 3 answers to this so far....

Comment: This maybe true, but people ask things differently and considering he is new to angular he may not know what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use `$scope.$watch` to listen for changes to the variable that you are passing.  Check out https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope to better understand how watch works

```
$scope.$watch('yourValue', function (oldValue, newValue) {
    //do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-model at your select input, then this code:

```
$scope.$watch('modelvalue', function(newValue, oldValue) {
     exampleService.setNewValue(selectedValue)
}, true);
```

Comment: yes, this is how I update in the service, my problem is the controller to know of this change